# ListViewItem cannot be selected

Tags: android, listview

I have a checkable item in my list view

```
public class CheckableMessageOut extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable{
    public CheckableMessageOut(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableMessageOut(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    LinearLayout wrapper;
    private boolean checked = false;

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        if (checked!=b){
            if (b){
                wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_msg_out_selected);
            } else {
                wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_msg_out);
            }
        }
        checked = b;
    }
```

I use it like this

```
<ru.kurganec.vk.messenger.ui.helper.CheckableMessageOut xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/label_msg_out"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_msg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="ad"

                />
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_attach"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/wrapper"

            android:text="06.06"/>

</ru.kurganec.
```

vk.messenger.ui.helper.CheckableMessageOut>

sometimes i add some views programmatically to the @id/list_attach and then something strage happens. I cannot select the item with attached view.

Whole It looks like this.

[image: Message with photo cannot be selected but others(without photos) can be selected]

by saying selected i mean checked.
I set this field  mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

Why can't i select the itemss?

---

UPDATE

Fragment class http://pastebin.com/BZRhahbi this is the main part of my app , so it looks like "god class" antipattern

Adapter class http://pastebin.com/Av7ntUmG

Adapter's item class http://pastebin.com/MdYc7Ksw

Comment: Do you have onClickListener implemented somewhere? I don't see it, and i"m wondering if you have it set to listen for the click.

Comment: yes i've implemented mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                handleMessageSelection();
            }
        }); But it does not actually changes layout  or check items manually, just handle the result of selection. Items should be checked by ListView itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem

Just add this to root view, if you have clickable views in ListView

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be here:

```
@Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        if (checked!=b){
            if (b){
                wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_msg_out_selected);
            } else {
                wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_msg_out);
            }
        }
        checked = b;
    }
```

Try:

```
@Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        if (checked!=b){
                wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_msg_out_selected);
              else {
                wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.label_msg_out);
            }
        }
        checked = b;
    }
```

The if(b) is unnecessary code.

Comment: is this a proper code? i didn't get your idea ;( what do you think is my problem?

Comment: Yes, I took out the `if(b)...`.  I think that might have cause your some problems. Give it a try and let me know. also, You might want to get away from comparing two boolean values. You could just say "if(b!=true)"... Can you post all your code? Like where you use setChecked()?

Comment: ahhh i forgot to mention, this method does not even called when i tap on th item with photo.

Comment: That's why I say, can you please post ALL your code, so I can see what you have going on? Thanks :)

Comment: They are really big. But if you really wana se it, i updated the post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if we are going to help, we need to know what is going on. Not to be rude, but you have just wasted a lot of time by posting code that isn't even being run. If it isn't being run, then that isn't the problem, the problem is somewhere else, but we don't know that. In the future please make sure you post ALL relevant code.

Comment: i ment this method is not called when i tap on message with attached photo, otherwise it is called. Anyway i'll take more time in the future, preparing the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to achieve this behavior is to use [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). That way the system will take care of switching drawables during state changes.
You can define such a drawable via XML.

For example, res/drawable/item_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_normal" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

and set it as the background resource of your checkable layout:

```
<ru.kurganec.vk.messenger.ui.helper.CheckableMessageOut xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/item_bg">
```

and your checkable layout code should be something like this:

```
public class CheckableMessageOut extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable{
public CheckableMessageOut(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CheckableMessageOut(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

LinearLayout wrapper;
private boolean checked = false;

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    if (checked) {
        final int[] states = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        mergeDrawableStates(states,
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked });
        return states;
    }
    return super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean c) {
    if (checked != c) {
        checked = c;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }
}
```

be sure to override the *onCreateDrawableState(int)* method, and add the state android.R.attr.state_checked to the drawable state array when required, and call *refreshDrawableState()* when checked state is changed.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.charlesharley.com/2012/programming/custom-drawable-states-in-android/) if there's any questions.